# R not finding anaconda installation

Tags: python, r

I am attempting to install an R package on my Ubuntu system and have encountered an error. (I do not receive this error when using a PC or Mac)

```
$ R
> install.packages("leiden")

...

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘leiden’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'leiden', details:
  call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
  error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I am confused because I can see pandas in my conda packages.

```
$ conda list | grep pandas
pandas                    1.0.1            py37h0573a6f_0
```

Also which python seems to give me my anaconda installation:

```
/home/usrname/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu in the Windows Unix subsystem
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: 1. Do you see `/home/usrname/anaconda3/bin/python` amount the output of `echo $PATH`? 2. Sorry, I'm confused--is this a Python question or an R question? 3. This question might be better suited for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), since it's more programming-related and isn't unique to Ubuntu in any way.

Comment: I can move it over there. I figured it might be something weird with my PATH or some since this worked fine with Windows and Mac installs. I have /home/usrname/anaconda3/bin but not /home/usrname/anaconda3/bin/python.

Comment: I guess there are many things to sort out.  In the shell, type `which R` and see which R you are using -- it could be the system's R or conda's.  As for conda, you need to install the `pandas` package explicitly using the `conda install` command.  Did you do that?

Comment: Yeah, it turned out that the R reticulate library was pulling from a different location than my which python. Creating an r-reticulate environment in anaconda allowed it to find my packages. Since this turned out to likely be more of an R issue should I delete this one and leave the Stack Overflow version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding another issue with a similar problem. Turns out I needed to activate the conda r-reticulate environment.

Take a look at a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220597/python-in-r-error-could-not-find-a-python-environment-for-usr-bin-python